# Publish NUnit test result grouped / labeled

Tags: jenkins, nunit, jenkins-plugins

I try to publish nunit tests results on jenkins, grouped (unit test, performance test). I use NUnit plugin to publish. I checked LabeledTestGroupsPublisher Plugin to group but it works probably only with junit result format. How to do it? Maybe the best way is to convert results to junit format? Thanks for answers.